# I can't find an element on a page through Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting to learn Selenium and wanted to implement authentication on the "https://mail.ru/" page. There are two "Login" buttons that, when clicked, open a window with an authentication form. However, Selenium does not see the elements of the page that appeared after clicking the "Login" buttons. I have tried searching by xPath, class_name, etc. How can I solve this problem?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


class TestLogMail:

    def test_log(self, browser_web):

        browser_web.get('https://mail.ru/')
        time.sleep(3)

        button_log = browser_web.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mailbox"]/div[1]/button').click()
        time.sleep(5)

        input_log = browser_web.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="username"]')
        input_log.send_keys('mail')
        time.sleep(5)

        button_input_pass = browser_web.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/button').click()
        time.sleep(5)

        input_pass = browser_web.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/input')
        input_pass.clear()
        input_pass.send_keys('pass')
        time.sleep(5)

        button_input_pass = browser_web.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(5)

        browser_web.save_screenshot('result_log.png')
```

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture
def browser_web():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDGba.png)

Comment: can you tell me what is the issue with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the iframe located on that web page:

[image]

You must switch to the iframe first before interacting with elements inside. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

```py
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.ag-popup__frame__layout__iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Now you can interact with elements inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The element *Account name* is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    browser_web.get("https://mail.ru/")
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='enter-mail-primary']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://account.mail.ru/login/?mode=simple']")))
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys('Daniil')
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    browser_web.get("https://mail.ru/")
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='enter-mail-primary']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://account.mail.ru/login/?mode=simple')]")))
    WebDriverWait(browser_web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys('Daniil')
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Danil]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in while clicking on login it is opening another popup and the elements are within an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://account.mail.ru/login/?mode=simple&amp;v=2.10.0&amp;account_host=account.mail.ru&amp;type=login&amp;allow_external=1&amp;app_id_mytracker=58519&amp;success_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fe.mail.ru%2Fmessages%2Finbox%3Fback%3D1&amp;project=home&amp;from=navi&amp;parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.ru%2F&amp;responsive=compact" class="ag-popup__frame__layout__iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is you can follow to handle this situation:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src="https://account.mail.ru/login/?mode=simple&amp;v=2.10.0&amp;account_host=account.mail.ru&amp;type=login&amp;allow_external=1&amp;app_id_mytracker=58519&amp;success_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fe.mail.ru%2Fmessages%2Finbox%3Fback%3D1&amp;project=home&amp;from=navi&amp;parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.ru%2F&amp;responsive=compact"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

And then you can proceed with your rest of the test steps.

I know this xpath is little weired. But you can ask your developer to put an ID to this iframe element which will definitely help to use *switch to frame id* method directly.